# Trying to figure out nested scopes in Rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a site where I'm making URLs look like the following (for users to view information):

```
/:state/:data_type/:category/:subcategory/:item_id
```

data_type is one of "directory", "articles", or "documents".  The idea is to store information for each state, based on categories and subcategories, and viewable as such.

Any particular piece of that is a valid path.  For instance:

/IN - show a home page for Indiana (controller region_home, action index)

/IN/directory - list of categories and subcategories for Indiana (controller region_categories)

/IN/directory/schools - list of subcategories under the "schools" category for Indiana (controller is region_subcategories)

/IN/directory/schools/elementary - list of elementary schools in Indiana (controller is region_directory, action index)

/IN/directory/schools/elementary/10-meridian-street - drilled down to the specific school (controller is region_directory, action is show)

This is mainly for showing the information.  I already have "slugs" created for all the regions, categories, subcategories, etc.  That part works.

I can actually make it work like this:

```
match ':region_slug/directory(/:category_slug(/:subcategory_slug(/:directory_entry_id)))' => 'region_directory#index', :as => :region_directory
```

The issue is that every request goes to the same controller/action, which then has to dispatch the request.

I can cut it into pieces:

```
match ':region_slug' => 'region_home#index'
match ':region_slug/directory' => 'region_categories#index'
match ':region_slug/directory/:category_slug' => 'region_subcategories#index'
match ':region_slug/directory/:category_slug/:subcategory_slug' => 'region_directory#index'
match ':region_slug/directory/:category_slug/:subcategory_slug/:directory_entry_id' => 'region_directory#show'
```

But that breaks DRY, and I have to repeat that for articles, etc.  I can't figure out how to do this with scopes.  Any ideas?

Comment: Michael, did you ever figure this out?  I'm looking at a similar problem in a current project, and I was wondering what your resolution was?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I'm still using essentially the last chunk of code that you can see there.